# PHP fileinfo is undefined function

Tags: php, mime-types, undefined-function

Whenever I try to get the mime content type from php, it echos:

> **Fatal error:** Class 'finfo' not found in **/home/jobynadel/finadel.com/video/finfo.php** on line **4**

or

> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined function finfo_open in **/home/jobynadel/finadel.com/video/finfo.php** on line **4**

I just can't figure it out!

The code I am using is:

```
$file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
// See constant value http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.constants.php#113687 
$mime_type = $file_info->buffer(file_get_contents($file));
```

Comment: Not an issue with php or laravel, your probably using namespaced code which means you need to import the class <?php

namespace Your\Namespace;

use finfo;

Answer (score 95):

Have a look at your php.ini file and check that the `fileinfo.so`or `php_fileinfo.dll` is activated (depending on your platform and version).

There should be a line similar to

```
extension=fileinfo.so
```

in your php.ini file

Comment: `$mime_type` return a string which contains `<mime type>; charset=<charset>` , so to get actual file mime type I have modified the question.

Comment: I use [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Llewellynvdm/74be373357e131b8775a7582c3de508b) that can be updated with the build script also found here.

Answer (score 28):

If you using XAMPP, you enable `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` in php.ini

Answer (score 21):

What version of PHP do you have? PHP 5.3.0 and later have Fileinfo built in, but on Windows you must enable it manually in your `php.ini`. You can find further information [in the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php).

Answer (score 9):

If you are using WAMP then Go to PHP extensions and enbale **PHP_fileinfo** and restart all serverices.

Answer (score 7):

Windows users: just edit **php.ini** and uncomment this line:

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

I.e. remove the preceding semicolon from

```
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Remember to restart Apache for new **php.ini** to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

For those have had it working fine, but then this error appears:

Some hosting providers (e.g., Dreamhost) allow customers to override default PHP settings in a configuration file, often with a path something like:

`~/.php/5.4/phprc`

That version number in the path can be a problem if you upgrade PHP (or it is upgraded on your behalf). Any custom settings from the prior version, including one enabling the fileinfo extension, will be missing in the newer version. Usually you can just copy the config file to the appropriate new config directory and restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue with PHP.I did the following steps:

```
 - make sure that the fileinfo extension is already installed if you are using < PHP 5.3.0.

 - Then you have to add in php.ini ;extension=fileinfo.so or
   ;extension=php_fileinfo.dll

 -  If you want to uncomment remove the semicolon(;)
   extension=fileinfo.so or extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

Then save and restart your web server.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP 7.3 or Higher

Change

```
;extension=fileinfo
```

To

```
extension=fileinfo
```

in php.ini file.