# .htaccess enable php fileinfo extension

Tags: php, file, .htaccess, fileinfo

I've used shared host for hosting my application and the version is `php5.3.27`. I'm getting an error like

```
 Call to undefined function finfo_open()
```

So I've gone through some articles where I suggested by enabling fileinfo extension in .htaccess. For the first time I'm getting this error. Please help me to get the solution. The work would be more appreciated.

Comment: What you see in your phpinfo?

Answer (score 9):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3579097/851273):

In your php.ini file, make sure you have something like this in it:

```
extension=fileinfo.so
```

or if you're on windows, `php_fileinfo.dll`.

Comment: Its shared hosting I do not have access to modify php.ini file. Is there any way to do it via .htaccess file?

Comment: @HussainKMRBehestee there's [plenty of ways to use a php.ini file in shared hosting](https://www.google.com/search?q=shared+hosting+php.ini&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), I've done it with Dreamhost. What the question didn't indicate was limit access to the hosting account, such as only access to the document root. On shared hosting, it's almost 100% they've disabled the feature of loading modules from htaccess, since the module would then be loaded FOR THE ENTIRE SERVER.

Comment: as he mentioned he is using shared hosting, obviously he is not seeking what to write in php.ini. so just copy paste is not the solution. I am sorry if you still do not get me.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy actually to access and modify php.ini file to enable file info. I just know by accident. So you search software/service which is there is select PHP version. Click it, and you will see your PHP Version. Try to change first (downgrade or upgrade, up to you) and then you will see that below there is fileinfo which in default not checklist yet. All you have to is, return the version of your PHP, and then checklist fileinfo, and click save. Thats it.

Comment: it worked, just change your version and u can see all the features checkbox, thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess, put this line:

#### Windows

```
php_value extension php_fileinfo.dll
```

#### *nix (Linux, Mac, etc)

```
php_value extension fileinfo.so
```

Comment: I think in newer PHP versions either this changed or is no longer needed, or you need to install it separately from an Aptitude package.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on shared hosting i continue with the answers above i.e. to include the extensions and is you are on go daddy just create a file in the root directory of your website and name it `.user.ini` this is how you change settings.