# How to Upload an Image in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, image-processing

I am new to Laravel 5. Actually I'm using Laravel Framework version 5.1.16. When uploading an image, it is uploading and saved in database table, but it is not moved to a specified folder.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is my controller code:

```php
public function addexpense(Request $request) {

  $inputs=Input::all();
  $validation = Validator::make($inputs, Expense::$rules);

  if($validation->fails()) {
    return Redirect::to('expenseaddform')->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
  }else{
    $input=Input::only('id','expense_date','expense_category_id','vendor_id','customer_id','amount','tax1_id','tax2_id','note','receipt');   

    $data->expense_date = $input['expense_date'];
    $data->expense_category_id = $input['expense_category_id'];
    $data->vendor_id = $input['vendor_id'];
    $data->customer_id = $input['customer_id'];
    $data->amount = $input['amount'];
    $data->tax1_id = $input['tax1_id'];
    $data->tax2_id = $input['tax2_id'];
    $data->note = $input['note'];

    $image = Input::file('receipt');
    $filename = date('Y-m-d-H:i:s')."-".$image->getClientOriginalName();
    Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(468, 249)->save('public/uploas/'. $filename);
    $data->receipt = $input['image'];

    $data->save();

    return redirect('expenseinfo');
  }
}
```

Form code:

```html
<form action="addexpense" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    Receipt:</td><td><input type="file" name="receipt"value="{{Input::old('receipt')}}">
    <input style="margin-left:30px"type="submit" value="Add" name="submit"> 
</form>
```

Comment: I have edited my post to a more accurate answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong with `Image::make()` function. Try the following:

```
Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(468, 249)->save(public_path() . '/uploads/' . $filename);
```

Comment: when i changed the code as you suggested it showing error as Class 'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider' not found

Comment: yes i followed those steps.but iam still getting the same error

Comment: State that as a separate question, so I can add my answer there. That I think suits it better. And don't forget to mark this as an answer.

Comment: now iam getting error MissingDependencyException in ImageManager.php line 123:
PHP Fileinfo extension must be installed/enabled to use Intervention Image. how to solve this

Comment: You should enable Fileinfo extension in your php.ini file. Follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20795948/2169355) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3579097/2169355)

Comment: thanks a lot for your immediate reply,but now i am getting error as Image source not readable.

Comment: Try like this once again: `Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(468, 249)->save(public_path() . '/uploads/' . $filename);`

Comment: i tried above code again but getting this errror Call to a member function getRealPath() on null.

Comment: That's because the $image variable is null. Check if it is like this: `$image = Input::file('receipt');` or you can directly use like this: `Input::file('receipt')->getRealPath();`

Comment: no luck getting the same error please give some solution to this problem,

Comment: What does `dd(Input::file('receipt'))` gives you?

Comment: actually the form data is saved in database but iam not getting receipt in specified folder

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(468, 249)->save(public_path('uploads/'). $filename);

For more information you can check the below link:
https://youtu.be/F92JpVWhDw4