# Wordpress plugin - call to undefined function finfo_open()

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I am trying to use the [CSV Me](http://wordpress.org/plugins/csv-me/) plugin in order to let our client upload a csv file to the database. When i try to upload a file as a test i get the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function finfo_open() in /home/diamondh/public_html/wp-content/plugins/csv-me/csv_me_index.php on line 110
```

I took a look at the file in question and found line 110 looking like:

```
                $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
```

As far as i know `finfo_open()` is a built in part of php so why would it be undefined?

*BONUS: Anyone know any better solutions for getting a csv into the wordpress database?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`finfo_open` is only available for php >= 5.3.0
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php

You may want to double check your server is up to date with `php_info()`

Comment: Ah this may be the issue! Let me check the server.

Comment: BONUS: Since csv is a pretty easy to read file format you could use `file_get_contents` and just parse it yourself

Comment: our server is 5.3.27...so its weird that i would be getting that error... also to your second comment i will probably use that and just right my own solution for the client rather then using this plugin.

Comment: It can be conditionally compiled in or added as a module. What platform are you running on?

Comment: It might be disabled: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579072/php-fileinfo-is-undefined-function

Comment: Worth adding, finfo is not enabled by default on Windows, you have to remove the semi colon from `;extension=php_fileinfo.dll` in your php.ini and then restart your web server for the changes to take affect