# How can I return a random asset from specific folder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I need to create a route where a random image or video is returned from a specific directory, how can I achieve this?

Comment: I would use `glob()` to return all of the files in the directory as an array. At which point you could get the length of the array and use `rand()` to return a random number between 0 and the array length. Plug that in as the array index and you've got a randomly selected file from a directory.

Comment: Could you please upvote my answer or accept it if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like this

```
Route::get('/random_media/', function() {

    // Get random files and pick one.
    $folder_path = public_path()."/your/path/here/"; // in my test case it's under /public folder
    $files = preg_grep('~\.(jpeg|jpg|png)$~', scandir($folder_path));
    $randomFile = $files[array_rand($files)]; // if 5 files found, random int between 0 and 4
    // Display it
    $file = File::get($folder_path.$randomFile);
    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header('Content-Type', mime_content_type($folder_path.$randomFile));
    return $response;

});
```

Using preg_grep instead of glob(). see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8541256/2468160

- If you see an error message (like I did) *Fatal error Call to undefined function finfo_open()* ---->
  [Fatal error: Call to undefined function finfo_open() in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072725/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-finfo-open-in-php)

[image: Tested]

My laravel version is 5.2.39, but I hope it works on 5.1.*