# php fileinfo files upload validation not working

Tags: php

I am trying to upload files and check if the uploading files are really pdf files, so I resort to the `fileinfo` functions in php.

The problem is that the code is not validating anything. It will allow all sorts of files to be uploaded including viruses. Currently, I am checking the file extension name but it's not secured and that's why am resorting to `fileinfo`. Can someone tell me what is wrong with the code? I am running php version 5.3.5

```php
if (function_exists('finfo_open')) {
    $mime = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime_type = finfo_file($mime, $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);
    if ($mime_type == "application/pdf") {
        echo "file is pdf";
    } else {
        echo "file is not pdf";
        finfo_close($mime);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Echo the `$mime_type` value to see what do you get.

Comment: If echo $mime_type it will not display or echo anything.

Comment: Do you get an error message at any point?

Comment: no error message at all

Comment: If no message is being displayed when this code is executed, then it would appear that if (function_exists('finfo_open')) is returning false. What happens if you remove that?

Comment: if i remove the if(function_exiist(finfo_open), it will display error Fatal error: Call to undefined function finfo_open() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wall\upload_plan.php

Comment: I think you may want to open a new question asking why finfo_open is missing from your php 5.3.5 setup. This should be available after 5.3.0. Possibly check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072725/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-finfo-open-in-php

Comment: Thanks @gmfm. The link saved me.  I went to php.ini and uncomment/remove the semicolon before fileinfo.dll 
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll

remove the semicolon ; (uncomment it)

extension=php_fileinfo.dll   I then save and restart apche and behold. its working now. Thanks. You can update your answer so that I can select it as correct or should I update the answer myself. between thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has to do with enabling fileinfo.dll in **php.ini** files.

I went to php.ini and uncomment/remove the semicolon before **;extension=php_fileinfo.dll**

so that it will look like below
**extension=php_fileinfo.dll**

I then save and restart apche and behold, its working now. Thanks