# Call to undefined function finfo_open() - PHP

Tags: php

I have this problem in php 5.4.45 : the fileinfo extension is enabled in php.ini and in the directory ext / the php_fileinfo.dll extension also is enabled, I restarted IIS but the problem still persists

```
if($archivo['size']>0){

    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $type=finfo_file($finfo, $archivo['tmp_name']);
    finfo_close($finfo);

    $validateFile=validar_medios($type);
    if (validar_galeria_media($type))
    {

        $done=false;
        if($comentario)$nombreArchivo1=$_POST['nombreArchivo1'];
        if($validateFile){
            $done=$objGstGaleria->saveMedio(
                $id_categoria,
                $archivo,
                $validateFile,
                $nombreArchivo1
            );
        }else {
            if($_FILES['archivo']['size']!=0)
                $msg.='No se pudo guardar el archivo 1 ['.$archivo['name'].'].<br />';
        }

        if(!$done && $archivo['size']<0) $msg.='No se pudo guardar el archivo 1 ['.$archivo['name'].'].<br />';

    }
    else{
        $tipo='error';
        $msg.='No se pudo cargar el archivo 1 ['.$archivo['name'].'], tiene un formato no v&aacute;lido.<br />';
    } // else



} // if
```

[image]

Comment: Anything here help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579072/php-fileinfo-is-undefined-function