# After upload image will appear error

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

After upload image "paycart" plugin will appear error. How do I fix this error?

```
Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in /home/project/public_html/lk/libraries/joomla/filter/input.php on line 531

Fatal error: Call to undefined function finfo_open() in /home/project/public_html/lk/components/com_paycart/paycart/libs/media.php on line 133
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your system is missing the function finfo_open()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php

This topic might interest you: [PHP fileinfo is undefined function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579072/php-fileinfo-is-undefined-function)

> Have a look at your php.ini file and check that the fileinfo.soor php_fileinfo.dll is activated (depending on your platform and version).
>
> There should be a line similar to `extension=fileinfo.so`
> in your php.ini file