# Call to undefined function Illuminate\Filesystem\finfo_file()

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following error showing up in my **laravel.log** file on a website I have running. How can I pin down where the error originates from? As the stack trace is so short I am unsure where to start.

> [2017-07-03 16:05:13] production.ERROR: exception 
>   'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined function Illuminate\Filesystem\finfo_file()' in /home/uksacbor/laravel-projects/attestation/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:254
>   Stack trace: #0 {main}

I've ran a search on the site's folder using sublime's global search for when `finfo_file()` is used and I've used it in a helper in a test...

```
private function prepareFileUpload($path, $name)
{
    TestCase::assertFileExists($path);

    $pathInfo = pathinfo($path);

    $copyPath = $pathInfo['dirname'] . $pathInfo['filename'] . '_copy' . $pathInfo['extension'];

    \File::copy($path, $copyPath);

    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $copyPath);

    return new \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile($copyPath, $name, $mime, filesize($copyPath), null, true);
}
```

Currently, my tests are all passing.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems your tests are run in an environment which uses different PHP installation. You may re-check.

Comment: I haven't run my tests in production, the error appears to be produced via user interaction.

Answer (score 9):

When you are managing the server yourself you should run

```
sudo pecl install fileinfo
```

from the commandline and edit php.ini (probably located at **/etc/php.ini**)

to contain the line

> extension=fileinfo.so

don't forget to restart the web server. Depending on your os and web stack this is something like

- service apache restart
- service httd restart
- service nginx restart

When using a shared hosting, you probably have an option in the webinterface to enable it from there. For example in directadmin

**Advanced features > Select PHP version**

[image]

And then

Tick the checkbox next to **fileinfo**

[image]

Don't forget to click save

Answer (score 4):

You are supposed to activate finfo_file()

[[check this link]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iagMc.png)

Answer (score 3):

As Michael Hamisi said, it's a method that is declared by a PECL PHP Extension named `fileinfo` that is commonly present on PHP installations.

it is used in Laravel to get information about files especially in upload cases.

you should check that the extension is enabled on your installations.
usually, when you do composer install, an error will be triggered telling you to activated the missing extension.

```
/**
 * (PHP >= 5.3.0, PECL fileinfo >= 0.1.0)
 * Return information about a file
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php
```

Answer (score 2):

You should install `fileinfo` using `WHM` or `DirectAdmin`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable fileinfo extension.

please refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24565508/7171624

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out how to fix the error itself I'm going to answer your question about how you can find out where the error originates from.

The error message tells us that you are not calling `finfo_file()` directly but that you are calling a method of `Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem` which uses it at line 254. So you need to search for where you are using this method from `Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem`.

If you are not using this method directly you could be using it indirectly through a dependency of yours. In this case you would need to search in your vendor directory for the usage of the method from `Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem`.