# Call to undefined function Illuminate\Filesystem\symlink()

Tags: php

I am installing a PHP script on my server as a test but I'm experiencing this error. I'm having trouble understanding what is wrong with the script code.

I enabled debug mode on the application and got this error message:

> Call to undefined function Illuminate\Filesystem\symlink()

This is the code
(The line that says: `return symlink($target, $link);` is the line where debug found the error):

```
public function copy($path, $target)
{
    return copy($path, $target);
}

/**
 * Create a symlink to the target file or directory. On Windows, a hard link is created if the target is a file.
 *
 * @param  string  $target
 * @param   string $link
 * @return void
 */
public function link($target, $link)
{
    if (!windows_os()) {
        return symlink($target, $link);
    }
    $mode = $this->isDirectory($target) ? 'J' : 'H';
    exec("mklink /{$mode} ".escapeshellarg($link).' '.escapeshellarg($target));
}

/**
 * Create a relative symlink to the target file or directory.
 *
 * @param  string  $target
 * @param   string $link
 * @return void
 */
public function relativeLink($target, $link){
    
}
```

Comment: Try to use \symlink($target, $link) instead of symlink($target, $link), symlink is a function of php, so you need the escape it to not use the current namespace

Comment: @Alex197 php check global namespace automatically,  as described here - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php, also, according to namespace provided in error message, it's laravel vendor code

Comment: check (lZF) extension and also for more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929092/call-to-undefined-function-illuminate-filesystem-finfo-file)

Comment: check (lZF) extension and also for more information look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929092/call-to-undefined-function-illuminate-filesystem-finfo-file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems you run it on a shared hosting, and some `php` functions are disabled by hosting provider for security reasons.

Comment: oh, I was unaware of that. Yes, I run it on a shared hosting.

Comment: Here is my php options. Does this have anything to do with this?
https://imgur.com/a/5fw0pwS

Comment: @PedroHenrique this is list of so-called extensions, it's ok, but you are interested in `disable_functions` configuration value, I'm not sure where it located in your panel. If `php.ini` is available for edit, you can find it there and set to empty string (`disable_functions=`)

Comment: I see. I'm getting in touch with my server support to talk to them about this. Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 8):

I have the same problem and the solution proved simple:

First, ssh to the server, navigate to your project folder, then delete the symlink from the public folder:

```
cd public
unlink storage
```

Finally, run the command to create the symlink manually (assuming we are still in public/):

```
ln -s ../storage/app/public storage
```

Answer (score 1):

for me, I was using cPanel, the Jupiter theme. I went to "Select PHP version" then to the options tab and deleted the function from the disabled functions input and saved. then I ran `php artisan storage:link` and it worked perfectly (ps: I'm using Laravel)
[image: disabled functions input]